# Regex matching a written list such as "New York, Texas, and Florida"

Tags: regex, regex-group

I need a regex that will match the following conditions for an arbitrarily long list where each capture can be **multiple words**. It will always have the oxford comma, if that helps.

1. `'New York'                     #=> ['New York']`
2. `'New York and Texas'           #=> ['New York', 'Texas']`
3. `'New York, Texas, and Florida' #=> ['New York', 'Texas', 'Florida']`

I found that `(.+?)(?:,|$)(?:\sand\s|$)?` will match 1 and 3 but not 2.

And `(.+?)(?:\sand\s|$)` will match 1 and 2 but not 3.

How can I match all 3?

Comment: Split with `\s*(?:\band\b|,)\s*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, almost! That captures ```['New York', 'Texas', '', 'Florida']```. Is there a way to not split on the empty string?

Comment: You may use `(?:\s*(?:\band\b|,))+\s*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That did it, thanks so much. Wish I could mark your comment as the correct answer.

Comment: Regex is not the best tool for the purpose. Probably not even suitable. How about "Trinidad and Tobago"? How about "Dallas, Texas"? I fear that the problem is not even properly formulated. From where do you take your data? Is there a limited list of possible values? What kind of validation has to be done on the resulting data structure? etc... Also "Bosnia and Herzegovina". The examples can continue...

Comment: @Zaataro I posted an answer with a demo and explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may split the text with the following pattern:

```
(?:\s*(?:\band\b|,))+\s*
```

**Details**

- `(?:\s*(?:\band\b|,))+` - 1 or more occurrences of:

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `(?:\band\b|,)` - `and` as a whole word or a comma
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace characters.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ekYQGr/1).

Note you may make it a bit more efficient if your regex engine supports possessive quantifiers:

```
(?:\s*+(?:\band\b|,))+\s*
      ^
```

Or atomic groups:

```
(?>\s*+(?:\band\b|,))+\s*
 ^^
```